# peritoneal dialysis Vs Hemodialysis?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, human-physiology, kidney, renal-physiology

Their are basically two types of dialysis: 1.peritoneal dialysis 2.hemodialysis, My Question is Why the peritoneal dialysis needs to be carried out on everyday BUT hemodialysis is carried out on only 3 days in a week?

Comment: Have you done any research on your own? Just googling the title of your question brings up lots of relevant results.

Comment: No I did not find the proper reason, just find out the pros and cons of both types of dialysis but I can't understand the proper reason.

Comment: Which type is more efficient at eliminating wastes may be the major factor.